# Is it possible to load a React App into another React App?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to load a React App into another React App?

I have created a React App but things have changed and now I want to create a dashboard around that App. Problem is I want both Apps to be able to run separated so I can work on App 1 in a separated repository and App 2 in a separated repository. But for deployment only deploy 1 App that loads in the other app.

**So my desired situation is as followed**

App 1 Dashboard loads App 2 as an component, while it is still possible to pass props from App 1 to App 2. (Authentication will happen in App 1 and both apps talk to the same backend rest api)

I have seen solutions such as an Iframe and redirect but this is not what I would like unless there is no other way.

Comment: Use iframes for loading of another web app to your app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. There are various resources available to do the same. I'd suggest going through below articles that will help you to find possible solutions.

https://medium.com/@tomsoderlund/micro-frontends-a-microservice-approach-to-front-end-web-development-f325ebdadc16

https://micro-frontends.org/

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach:

APP1 should be this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Your header contents -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('someComponentInitialized', () => {
        SomeComponent(
            {someConfig: 'someValue'}, 
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain-where-app2-lives.ext/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

APP2 should be this (bundle.js called in App 1)

```
import SomeComponent from './components/someComponent';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const SomeComponent = (config, element) => {
    ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent config={config} />,
        element
    );
};

window.SomeComponent = SomeComponent;
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('someComponentInitialized'));
```

What this does:

App2 is adding the SomeComponent method to the global window scope. In App1, you call that method and pass the arguments, argument 1 is the config and argument 2 is the element you want SomeComponent to be printed on.

Comment: I tried to test this but I did not succeed. Could you please give a more detailed explanation ?